# Getting sendmail to work on ubuntu 14.04 desktop

Tags: sendmail, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to get the PHP mail() command to send an email from my development machine (ubuntu 14.04 desktop).

So I have installed sendmail like this:

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

Next, I test sendmail like this:

```
mail me@email.com < message.txt
```

That command hangs for about 40 seconds and then exits without any message.
The email does not arrive.

I have no idea where to look to start debugging this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1 Send a test message in verbose mode
2 check the log files

```
#!/bin/sh
TO='john.doe@example.net'
/usr/sbin/sendmail -v -i $TO <<END
To: $TO
Subject: test

Body of test message
END
```